# Mac App WebView background

Tags: objective-c, macos, background, webview

How is it possible to set the an image as background of the WebView in a Mac App? Because the WebView has that "bouncing" effect, if you scroll further down than the content, the background is usually just white. Is it possible to set a Background-image like it is possible for the UIWebView?

EDIT: The alternate way would be to completely deactivate the bouncing-effect of the webView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating this webview programically then create an image then create the webview. Make sure their positions (x,y) and sizes (height, width) are the same.

If you are doing this through IB put down an image (litterally just drag an image) then put the webview on top of it.

Comment: Okay. First, thanks for your answer. But how can I make an repeating image? (The image is 100x100 and should be the background of the whole window)

Comment: @DRP96 do you mean one big image or several small images? Also are you programming the webview or doing it in IB?

Comment: The webview was created in the Interface Builder, but it's also "linked" in the code. I meant several small images. (But if it's not possible I can also use photoshop and make one big image of it)

Comment: I would suggest to photoshop. When you are done with that delete the webview, drag the image in from finder, resize it, adjust it so when the window resizes it will also resize, link it, then put in a new webview and link that. (I suggest deleting the webview because you cannot hide it and you want to make sure that the webview is in front.

Comment: Okay, I did it with Photoshop now. It also worked without deleting the WebView, I just dragged the Image up in the Object-list on the left, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15967/discussion-between-drp96-and-coder404)

Comment: In case anyone is still wondering how to disable the bouncing effect: [Disable Rubber Band Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820479/1370927)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way I found that stops the bouncing:

```
id sub = self.web.subviews[0];
if ([sub isKindOfClass:[WebFrameView class]])
    [sub setAllowsScrolling:NO];
```

The class check may not be needed, but I like to make sure.

Comment: Although I don't really need this anymore, thanks for your answer! I'll check it out when I have time.

Comment: It relies on the webview not needing to scroll at all, which was fine for my app but may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

We can add background image in WebView using cocoa. to do this we need to add css for body tag.

**Create a webview:**

```
WebView *webView;
```

**Fetch image form bundle path:**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my-bg" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

**write Css for body tag.**

```
NSMutableString *htmlBuilder = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[htmlBuilder appendString:@"body {"];
[htmlBuilder appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" background-image: url('file://%@');",path]];
[htmlBuilder appendString:@"}"];
```

**Load this image on webview**

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlBuilder baseURL:nil];
[webView setDrawsBackground:NO];
```

Your image will be added in background on webview.