# How to enable elasticity in WebView?

Tags: cocoa, webview, nsscrollview

When developing OS X apps in Cocoa, WebView does not have over-scroll elasticity (i.e., the bouncy scrolling that Safari has on OS X).  How do you enable it?

Answer (score 3):

After much putzing, I figured out the answer.  The key is to get a handle of the scroll view that WebView creates (but does not publicly expose).  Here is how to do it:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
    NSScrollView * scrollView = (NSScrollView *)([[[self mainFrame] frameView] subviews][0]);
    [scrollView setHorizontalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityAutomatic];
    [scrollView setVerticalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityAutomatic];
}
```

Note that this needs to be done whenever the frame's URL is set.

Comment: You should use `frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView`. See a similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11820479/199607